# Convincing the compiler that a GAT has the same type as another GAT

Tags: rust, specialization, generic-const-exprs

I was playing with some code, trying to see how wild I can get.

The basic idea came to me when implementing merge sort with a custom comparator. We need to pass down the comparator (`impl FnMut`), but we cannot pass it owned because we need to pass it twice (for each subroutine). The classic workaround is to take `&mut impl FnMut`. But then, if the comparator is a Zero-Sized-Type (which is the case in the common case of just forwarding to the sorted type's `PartialOrd` implementation, via `PartialOrd::lt` which is a function item those a ZST), we pass down a real reference while we could avoid it, which is bad for optimization. Maybe the compiler can eliminate this parameter, but can we do better?

So, using specialization I thought to build a type that constructs the instance on-the-fly for ZSTs but stores a real reference for other types. This also requires `generic_const_exprs`, so let's go wild with the most unstable features!

First, we need a trait to represent ZSTs so we can specialize on it:

```rust
#![feature(specialization, generic_const_exprs)]

trait IsZst {}

struct Assert<const COND: bool>;
trait IsTrue {}
impl IsTrue for Assert<true> {}

impl<T> IsZst for T where Assert<{ std::mem::size_of::<T>() == 0 }>: IsTrue {}
```

Then we can build another trait, that will have two associated types: one which is the shared reference type, and the other which is the mutable reference type:

```rust
pub trait EfficientZstRep {
    type SharedRef<'a>: Deref<Target = Self> + From<&'a Self> + Copy
    where
        Self: 'a;
    type MutRef<'a>: Deref<Target = Self> + DerefMut + From<&'a mut Self>
    where
        Self: 'a;
}
```

The default implementation is easy - just use normal references:

```rust
impl<T: ?Sized> EfficientZstRep for T {
    default type SharedRef<'a> = &'a T
    where
        Self: 'a;
    default type MutRef<'a> = &'a mut T
    where
        Self: 'a;
}
```

For ZSTs, we need to have our own structs:

```rust
pub struct SharedZstRef<'a, T>(PhantomData<&'a T>);

impl<'a, T: IsZst> From<&'a T> for SharedZstRef<'a, T> {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn from(_v: &'a T) -> Self {
        Self(PhantomData)
    }
}

impl<T: IsZst> Deref for SharedZstRef<'_, T> {
    type Target = T;
    #[inline(always)]
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        unsafe { NonNull::dangling().as_ref() }
    }
}

impl<T> Clone for SharedZstRef<'_, T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        *self
    }
}

impl<T> Copy for SharedZstRef<'_, T> {}

pub struct MutZstRef<'a, T>(PhantomData<&'a mut T>);

impl<'a, T: IsZst> From<&'a mut T> for MutZstRef<'a, T> {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn from(_v: &'a mut T) -> Self {
        Self(PhantomData)
    }
}

impl<T: IsZst> Deref for MutZstRef<'_, T> {
    type Target = T;
    #[inline(always)]
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        unsafe { NonNull::dangling().as_ref() }
    }
}

impl<T: IsZst> DerefMut for MutZstRef<'_, T> {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        unsafe { NonNull::dangling().as_mut() }
    }
}

impl<T: IsZst> EfficientZstRep for T {
    type SharedRef<'a> = SharedZstRef<'a, T>
    where
        Self: 'a;
    type MutRef<'a> = MutZstRef<'a, T>
    where
        Self: 'a;
}
```

And now shared references work great! (Well, a little verbose, but who cares?)

```rust
fn foo<T: Fn()>(v: T) {
    bar::<T>(<_>::from(&v));
}

fn bar<T: Fn()>(v: <T as EfficientZstRep>::SharedRef<'_>) {
    v();
    bar::<T>(v);
    bar::<T>(v);
}
```

But with mutable references we got a problem: shared references are `Copy`, so we can use them twice, but mutable references are not. Usually, they are automagically reborrowed, so it *looks* like they are copied, but this is a different mechansim.

The usual workaround when you have a type that wrap mutable references (see e.g. [the unstable `std::io::BorrowedCursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.BorrowedCursor.html#method.reborrow), or [`Pin`'s `as_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/struct.Pin.html#method.as_mut)) is to have some method that take `&'b mut self` and returns `Self` with `'b` lifetime. Let's express that in a trait:

```rust
pub trait EfficientZstRep {
    type SharedRef<'a>: Deref<Target = Self> + From<&'a Self> + Copy
    where
        Self: 'a;
    type MutRef<'a>: Deref<Target = Self> + DerefMut + Reborrow + From<&'a mut Self>
    // `Reborrow` is new!
    where
        Self: 'a;
}

pub trait Reborrow: Deref {
    type Result<'a>: Deref<Target = Self::Target> + DerefMut + Reborrow + From<&'a mut Self::Target>
    where
        Self: 'a;
    fn reborrow(&mut self) -> Self::Result<'_>;
}

impl<T: ?Sized> Reborrow for &'_ mut T {
    type Result<'b> = &'b mut T
    where
        Self: 'b;
    #[inline(always)]
    fn reborrow(&mut self) -> Self::Result<'_> {
        &mut **self
    }
}

impl<T: IsZst> Reborrow for MutZstRef<'_, T> {
    type Result<'b> = MutZstRef<'b, T>
    where
        Self: 'b;
    #[inline(always)]
    fn reborrow(&mut self) -> Self::Result<'_> {
        Self(PhantomData)
    }
}
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work:

```rust
fn foo<T: FnMut()>(mut v: T) {
    bar::<T>(<_>::from(&mut v));
}

fn bar<T: FnMut()>(mut v: <T as EfficientZstRep>::MutRef<'_>) {
    v();
    bar::<T>(v.reborrow());
    bar::<T>(v);
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:124:14
    |
124 |     bar::<T>(v.reborrow());
    |     -------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `EfficientZstRep::MutRef`, found `Reborrow::Result`
    |     |
    |     arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected associated type `<T as EfficientZstRep>::MutRef<'_>`
               found associated type `<<T as EfficientZstRep>::MutRef<'_> as Reborrow>::Result<'_>`
    = note: an associated type was expected, but a different one was found
note: function defined here
   --> src/main.rs:122:4
    |
122 | fn bar<T: FnMut()>(mut v: <T as EfficientZstRep>::MutRef<'_>) {
    |    ^^^             -----------------------------------------
help: try removing the method call
    |
124 -     bar::<T>(v.reborrow());
124 +     bar::<T>(v);
    |
```

The problem is that the compiler is unable to conclude that `v.reborrow()` is also `MutRef`, just with another lifetime.

Trying to get rid of the explicit `::<T>` doesn't work either:

```rust
fn bar<T: FnMut()>(mut v: <T as EfficientZstRep>::MutRef<'_>) {
    v();
    bar(v.reborrow());
    bar::<T>(v);
}
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
   --> src/main.rs:124:5
    |
124 |     bar(v.reborrow());
    |     ^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the function `bar`
    |
help: consider specifying the generic argument
    |
124 |     bar::<T>(v.reborrow());
    |        +++++

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
   --> src/main.rs:124:5
    |
124 |     bar(v.reborrow());
    |     ^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the function `bar`
    |
note: multiple `impl`s or `where` clauses satisfying `_: FnMut<()>` found
   --> src/main.rs:122:11
    |
122 | fn bar<T: FnMut()>(mut v: <T as EfficientZstRep>::MutRef<'_>) {
    |           ^^^^^^^
    = note: and more `impl`s found in the following crates: `alloc`, `core`:
            - impl<A, F> FnMut<A> for &F
              where A: Tuple, F: Fn<A>, F: ?Sized;
            - impl<A, F> FnMut<A> for &mut F
              where A: Tuple, F: FnMut<A>, F: ?Sized;
            - impl<Args, F, A> FnMut<Args> for Box<F, A>
              where Args: Tuple, F: FnMut<Args>, A: Allocator, F: ?Sized;
note: required by a bound in `bar`
   --> src/main.rs:122:11
    |
122 | fn bar<T: FnMut()>(mut v: <T as EfficientZstRep>::MutRef<'_>) {
    |           ^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `bar`
help: consider specifying the generic argument
    |
124 |     bar::<T>(v.reborrow());
    |        +++++
```

And I think that even if this would pass inference, this still wouldn't work as this will create infinite generic instantiations.

I also tried to create a giant `where` clause that will convince the compiler the types are the same:

```rust
pub trait Reborrow: Deref {
    type Result<'a>: Deref<Target = Self::Target> + DerefMut + Reborrow + From<&'a mut Self::Target>
    where
        Self: 'a,
        Self::Target: EfficientZstRep<MutRef<'a> = Self::Result<'a>>;
    fn reborrow(&mut self) -> Self::Result<'_>;
}
```

But this doesn't work either:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `<&mut T as Reborrow>::Result<'_> == <T as EfficientZstRep>::MutRef<'_>`
  --> src/main.rs:37:31
   |
37 |     fn reborrow(&mut self) -> Self::Result<'_> {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `<MutZstRef<'_, T> as Reborrow>::Result<'_> == MutZstRef<'_, T>`
  --> src/main.rs:96:31
   |
96 |     fn reborrow(&mut self) -> Self::Result<'_> {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand why - as opposed to bounds after the colon in GATs, bounds in the `where` clause are something the implementor must consider and not the user - but I haven't found a way to specify this bound within the colon.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=618aee78e9543ae295cd7ec92c57dd63).

Comment: Just to confirm, by "ZST" you mean zero-sized-types?

Comment: @Dai A Zero-Sized-Type; a type that has a size in memory of zero, does not occupy any bytes.